# find missing records by joining 2 table

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-server-2012, subquery

**Master Table**

Will show every records that available DetailsTable except the records with ***Ops_Stat=A***

```
+---------+----------+-------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Row_Num | Ops_Stat | RunID | Cust_ID |  Name   |    Date             |                                                       |
+---------+----------+-------+---------+---------+---------------------+-------------------------------------------------------+
|       1 | U        | A123  | AAA1111 | Hulk    | 2019-09-01 01.05.01 | < No need capture this row in expected result         |
|       2 | U        | B456  | AAA1111 | Hulk    | 2019-07-01 01.04.11 |                                                       |
|       3 | U        | C789  | AAA1111 | IronMan | 2019-05-01 01.03.01 |                                                       |
|       4 | A        | D123  | AAA1111 | Spidey  | 2019-01-01 01.02.01 | < Need capture this row and show in expected result   |
|       1 | A        | U489  | BBB2222 | Marvel  | 2019-10-10 02.02.02 | < no need get this if not match of Cust_ID in Details |
|       2 | A        | Y789  | BBB2222 | Marvel  | 2019-09-10 02.02.02 | < no need get this if not match of Cust_ID in Details |
+---------+----------+-------+---------+---------+------------+----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Details**

-If there is update on the field (Name, Reason, and more columns) only will show on this table

-Just need to capture the records where **Status='Comp'**

```
+---------+-------+---------+---------+--------+---------------------+--------+---------------------------+
| Row_Num | RunID | Cust_ID |  Name   | Reason |    Date             | Status |                           |
+---------+-------+---------+---------+--------+---------------------+--------+---------------------------+
|       1 | A123  | AAA1111 | Hulk    |        | 2019-09-01 01.05.40 | Pend   | << Ignore status = 'Pend' |
|       2 | B456  | AAA1111 | Hulk    | A      | 2019-07-01 01.04.20 | Comp   |                           |
|       3 | C789  | AAA1111 | IronMan | A      | 2019-05-01 01.03.50 | Comp   |                           |
+---------+-------+---------+---------+--------+---------------------+--------+---------------------------+
```

**Expected result**

```
+----------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| Ops_Stat | RunID   | Cust_ID |  Name   | Reason |       Date        | Status |                                      |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| U        | B456    | AAA1111 | Hulk    | A      | 20190701 01.04.20 | Comp   | << take every field in Details table |
| U        | C789    | AAA1111 | IronMan | A      | 20190501 01.03.50 | Comp   | << take every field in Details table |
| A        | D123    | AAA1111 | Spidey  |        | 20190101 01.02.01 |        | << take every field in Master table  |
+----------+---------+---------+---------+--------+-------------------+--------+--------------------------------------+
```

1. Cust_ID is the key to link between Master and Details table
2. In the expected result, need to include records where Ops_Stat = A; and if matching of Cust_ID in Master and Details table
3. In the expected result, no need get Ops_Stat=A, if there is no matching of Cust_ID in Details table.
4. In the expected result, need to exclude the records where Details table status = Pend
5. Please notice on the datetime. When Ops_stat=A, take the datetime in MasterTable,  but when Ops_stat not equal A, take datetime in DetailsTable

Attempted:

```
select * 
from Master m
left join Details d on m.Cust_ID = d.Cust_ID
where d.Status = 'Comp'
```

Based the attempted above, my findings as below

1. All records from Master table (whether Status = pend or com, no matching key in details table, status in details table all become 'Comp' instead of Pend + Comp

**You may try your code here** : **[SQL Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=5297880b8b9870282aeff335480d11c8)**

Comment: Did you already write any query for this? What issue you are facing in that? Can you share that query here?

Comment: What is your question here exactly? You've stated a list of requirements, but not asked anything. What is *your* question? What have you tried and why didn't it work? Also, what do you mean you "dealing with 10mils"? What's a mils?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya updated as above for my attempt .

Comment: Performing an `OUTER JOIN` and then referencing the a column from the joined table in the `WHERE` without handling `NULL` values turns it into an implicit `INNER JOIN`

Comment: @Larnu sorry i dont get your meaning :(

Answer (score 0):

In this case I'll suggest to break result set into two sub queries i.e.

First result set will be depending upon Status='Comp'

```
select * 
from Master m
inner join Details d 
on m.Cust_ID = d.Cust_ID
where d.Status = 'Comp'
```

And than the second result set which contains data just from MasterTable

```
select * 
from Master m 
left join Details d 
on m.cust_Id = d.Cust_ID 
where ops_stat='A'
```

**Edit**

For joining these two records either go with UNION ALL,

```
select m.RowNum, m.Ops_Stat, m.RunID, m.Cust_ID, m.Name, m.DateTime, 
d.RowNum, d.RunID, d.Cust_ID, d.Name, d.Reason, d.DateTime, d.Status
from m
inner join d 
on m.Cust_ID = d.Cust_ID and m.runId=d.runId
where d.Status = 'Comp'

UNION ALL

select m.RowNum, m.Ops_Stat, m.RunID, m.Cust_ID, m.Name, m.DateTime, 
d.RowNum, d.RunID, d.Cust_ID, d.Name, d.Reason, d.DateTime, ISNULL(d.Status,'COMP') 
from m 
left join d 
on m.cust_Id = d.Cust_ID and m.runId=d.runId
where ops_stat='A'
```

or you can insert records into third temporary table, I'll not recommend this as it will cost insert operations.

Result set on SQL fiddle is [OUTPUT](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=800ecdf1bd19808c51073cdfcdae2eec)

Comment: Pls advise how am i joining them into 1 table?

Comment: dbfiddle.uk/… Amended to my version using your script as base (need excluded those Cust_ID not available in Details table). But this method kinda "exhausted" if has many columns. I do have about 50cols

Comment: If output of any specific column needs to be altered than in that case we need to mention that column. **First** You can try generating column list either from sys.columns for given table if you don't want to invest time in writing those column names yourself. **Second** press ALT+F1 while selecting table name, it will output all columns of given table and then you can select them and in your required queries. Give it a try and let me know your findings :)

Answer (score 0):

Please try the code below.

select m.Ops_stat,m.RunID,m.Cust_ID,m.Name,d.Reason,case when isnull(d.status,'') = '' then m.Date else d.date end ddate,d.Status
from Master m
left join Details d on m.Cust_ID = d.Cust_ID AND m.RunID = d.RunID
where ISNULL(d.Status,'') <> 'Pend'

Comment: Not really working as it will shows all records that available in Master table

Comment: I updated my answer base on the fields required in the problem.

Comment: Not really working as it will shows all records that available in Master table.  i think we should get both table date as if you see clearly the date of RunID = B456, C789 follow Master's table datetime.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I missed the dates.. I update my answer again

Comment: updated my requirement as above. i just realized i just mentioned status all become pending.